# OnContentPrepare not working in custom Joomla Plugin

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api

I have made other plugins for Joomla 4 but I am still a novice. The past two days I have been searching for a solution, it's becoming quite frustrating. I have brought back my code in the php file to just to show me anything, in this case 'Hello There'. I have searched reporting, the log just shows it loads the plugin and nothing... The plugin does install correctly, uninstalls too, the shortcode is simple {climate} and all the files are in place, Joomla also finds the plugin because I have tested it even on a clean install of Joomla 4. Just the onContentPrepare doesnt do anything at all which is weird.. Can anyone help me?? :

```
<?php
/**
 * @version    1.0.0
 * @package    myclimatetable (plugin)
 * @author     AN
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2023 AN
 * @license    GNU/GPL license: https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 */

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgContentClimateTable extends JPlugin 
{
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart) 
    {
        $article->text = preg_replace('/{climate}/', 'Hello there', $article->text);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My manifest file is okay, I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="4.0" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
    <name>plg_content_myclimatetable</name>
    <author>AN</author>
    <creationDate>September 2023</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2023 Harper Douglas Max</copyright>
    <license>NU/GPL license: https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html</license>
    <authorEmail>AN</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>AN</authorUrl>
    <version>0.02</version>
    <description>A plugin that allows climate tables to be inserted from WMO</description>

    <!-- Files and folders included in the plugin -->
    <files>
        <filename plugin="myclimatetable">myclimatetable.php</filename>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>full_city_list.csv</filename>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <folder>logs</folder>
    </files>
    <languages folder="language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_myclimatetable.sys.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_myclimatetable.ini</language>
        <language tag="nl-NL">nl-NL/nl-NL.plg_content_myclimatetable.sys.ini</language>
        <language tag="nl-NL">nl-NL/nl-NL.plg_content_myclimatetable.ini</language>
    </languages>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla), the class name should be in format `plg<PluginGroup><PluginName>` (casing doesn't matter for J3 and older style plugins). The name of your plugin is `myclimatetable`, as defined by `plugin` attribute in the XML file. Therefore, the class name should be `PlgContentMyClimateTable`, not `PlgContentClimateTable`.

Comment: Thank you so much! What a silly oversight!